# Control.BeginInvoke does not call delegate when UI function is idle

Tags: c#, controls

I am modifying a windows desktop application that works with some external hardware.  When the user activates the hardware from the application a progress (UI) form is started.  This form creates a thread that performs all of the work with the hardware.  The problem comes when I try to report progress back to the UI thread.  It appears that the first of my Control.BeginInvoke ("Negotiating message") works fine.  However, the second one (first adjustment to progressbar) never seems to call it's delegate and as a result the application locks up on the subsequent endinvoke.  I believe the issue is that the GUI is now in an idle state, but I am not sure how to fix the situation.  Any help would be appreciated.  Code found below:

In the UI Load Method Thread:

```
    private void frmTwainAquire_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Show the GUI
            this.Visible = showGUI;
            pbScanningProgress.Value = 0;
            btnCancel.Enabled = false;
            btnCancel.Visible = false;

            // Set the delegates.
            SetScanMessageDelegate = new SetScanMessage(this.SetScanMessageMethod);
            SetRegistrationMessageDelegate = new SetRegistrationMessage(this.SetRegistrationMessageMethod);
            AddScanProgressDelegate = new AddScanProgress(this.AddScanProgressMethod);
            AddRecogProgressDelegate = new AddRecogProgress(this.AddRecogProgressMethod);

            // Set progress bars.
            pbScanningProgress.Value = 0;
            pbRecognition.Value = 0;
            abortScan = false;

            // Create thread here!
            twainInstance = new rScan.Twain();
            rScanning = new rScanThread(this, twainInstance);

            // Start the thread.
            rScanning.tScan = new Thread(rScanning.Scan);
            rScanning.tScan.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error checking here.
        }
    }
```

Delegate Methods:

```
public void SetScanMessageMethod(string scanMessage)
    {
        this.lblScanMessage.Text = scanMessage;
    }

    public void SetRegistrationMessageMethod(string recogMessage)
    {
        this.lblRecognition.Text = recogMessage;
    }

    public void AddScanProgressMethod(int progress)
    {
        this.pbScanningProgress.Value += progress;
    }

    public void AddRecogProgressMethod(int progress)
    {
        this.pbRecognition.Value += progress;
    }
```

Thread method that is giving the problem.  Please note that the thread is in a different class then the previous two code blocks (both are in the UI class): 
public class rScanThread : IMessageFilter

```
public void Scan()
    {
        // Set progress bar message.
        IAsyncResult result;
        if (frmTwainAquireInstance.lblScanMessage.IsHandleCreated && frmTwainAquireInstance.lblScanMessage.InvokeRequired)
        {
            result = frmTwainAquireInstance.lblScanMessage.BeginInvoke(frmTwainAquireInstance.SetScanMessageDelegate, "Negotiating Capabilities with Scanner.");
            frmTwainAquireInstance.lblScanMessage.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        else
        {
            frmTwainAquireInstance.lblScanMessage.Text = "Negotiating Capabilities with Scanner.";
        }

        // Start the intialization of the rScan process.
        bool intializeSuccess = twainInstance.Initialize(frmTwainAquireInstance.Handle);

        // If the process could not be started then quit.
        if (!intializeSuccess)
        {
            frmTwainAquireInstance.Close();
            return;
        }

        if (frmTwainAquireInstance.pbScanningProgress.IsHandleCreated && frmTwainAquireInstance.pbScanningProgress.InvokeRequired)
        {
            result = frmTwainAquireInstance.pbScanningProgress.BeginInvoke(frmTwainAquireInstance.AddScanProgressDelegate, 33);
            frmTwainAquireInstance.pbScanningProgress.EndInvoke(result);  // Lock up here.
        }
        else
        {
            frmTwainAquireInstance.pbScanningProgress.Value += 33;
        }

      // Do more work after.  The code never makes it this far.

    } // End of rScanThread.Scan()
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever really call `EndInvoke` on that method.  If you want a blocking call to the UI just use `Invoke`, if you don't `BeginInvoke` and then just fire and forget (which is usually appropriate).  Also there's no need for `InvokeRequired`.  You're only ever running the method from a background thread, so you *know* that invoke is required already.

Comment: Don't call EndInvoke(), it isn't required and likely to cause deadlock.  That's probably not the solution to your problem, TWAIN code tends to be very picky about getting called from the right thread.  An STA thread that pumps a message loop, like your UI thread.

Comment: Servy and Mr. Passant thank you both for your input. I have removed the EndInvoke and InvokeRequired calls.  As Mr. Passant said, it had no effect on the issue of the delegate not being called.  The application no longer deadlocks, so I count it as a move in the right direction.